# Pass R object to Observable in Quarto

Tags: r, quarto

I am trying to use R and Observable together in a quarto doc as per: https://quarto.org/docs/interactive/ojs/

As far as I can tell, one uses the `ojs_define` function to make data available to observable. So for the example below I am trying that with `palmerpenguins::penguins_raw`:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
---

```{r}
ojs_define(data = palmerpenguins::penguins_raw)
```


```{ojs}
viewof bill_length_min = Inputs.range(
  [32, 50], 
  {value: 35, step: 1, label: "Bill length (min):"}
)
viewof islands = Inputs.checkbox(
  ["Torgersen", "Biscoe", "Dream"], 
  { value: ["Torgersen", "Biscoe"], 
    label: "Islands:"
  }
)
```


```{ojs}
filtered = data.filter(function(penguin) {
  return bill_length_min < penguin.bill_length_mm &&
         islands.includes(penguin.island);
})
```

```{ojs}
Plot.rectY(filtered, 
  Plot.binX(
    {y: "count"}, 
    {x: "body_mass_g", fill: "species", thresholds: 20}
  ))
  .plot({
    facet: {
      data: filtered,
      x: "sex",
      y: "species",
      marginRight: 80
    },
    marks: [
      Plot.frame(),
    ]
  }
)
```
````

However when I render I get these types of errors:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F09CA.png

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things to note,

**Firstly**, you are using  `palmerpenguins::penguins_raw` data, which has no columns named `bill_length_min`, `bill_length_mm`. Maybe you are intending to use `palmerpenguins::penguins`.

**Secondly**, you need to do `transpose(data)` before doing filter operation in the ojs chunk. Because from the [documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/interactive/ojs/#data-sources),

> the `Plot` function expects data by row rather than by column, so we `transpose()` it before filtering

---

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
---

```{r}
ojs_define(data = palmerpenguins::penguins)
```


```{ojs}
viewof bill_length_min = Inputs.range(
  [32, 50],
  {value: 35, step: 1, label: "Bill length (min):"}
)
viewof islands = Inputs.checkbox(
  ["Torgersen", "Biscoe", "Dream"],
  { value: ["Torgersen", "Biscoe"],
    label: "Islands:"
  }
)
```


```{ojs}
filtered = transpose(data).filter(function(penguin) {
  return bill_length_min < penguin.bill_length_mm &&
         islands.includes(penguin.island);
})
```

```{ojs}
Plot.rectY(filtered,
  Plot.binX(
    {y: "count"},
    {x: "body_mass_g", fill: "species", thresholds: 20}
  ))
  .plot({
    facet: {
      data: filtered,
      x: "sex",
      y: "species",
      marginRight: 80
    },
    marks: [
      Plot.frame(),
    ]
  }
)
```
````

---